# Web Browser Module - Can't Loop through a list of URLs with 'for' Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-webbrowser

I have the following code which will import a .txt file with a list of urls that, with the for statement, I'd like open one by one. Unfortunately webbrowser won't open the link by one by one, but it would open a new Chrome tab with the url "https://link" hence giving me a "about:blank" tab. Do you guys have any idea how to make it work?Thank you very much!

```
import webbrowser as wb
chrome="/Users/jamesnorton/applications %s"
file=open('File.txt')
for link in file:
    wb.get("google").open_new('link')
```

Answer (score -2):

You are passing a string as parameter not a variable.

Try this instead:

```
import webbrowser as wb
chrome="/Users/jamesnorton/applications %s"
file=open(file='File.txt',mode='r')
links = file.read()
lines = links.splitlines()
for link in lines:
    wb.get("google").open_new(link)
```

Comment: Tell me if problem is not solved

Comment: That will not solve the problem due in part to a syntax error. Strings are variables albeit immutable